# И она мысленно унеслась воспоминаниями

Tags: плеоназм

*И она мысленно унеслась куда-то воспоминаниями.*

Является ли данное выражение плеоназмом? Насколько оно благозвучно?

Comment: Мне кажется тут не в плеоназме дело, а в том что "она мысленно унеслась" и "воспоминаниями": ..дальнейшее течение мыслей её уносило всё дальше и дальше, куда-то в океан воспоминаний. Воспоминания и мысли - слишком абстрактные понятия, и лучше их оставить таковыми. берете конкретные образы вещей и нанизываете на них абстракции.

Comment: Дело даже не в плеоназме, вы уберите слово "мысленно" и предложение по-прежнему будет стилистически плохим. Примерно как "Пыль унеслась ветром"

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что предложение лучше изменить, так как  слова «***мысленно***» и «***воспоминаниями***» все-таки нежелательно употреблять **в одном предложении** (унеслась как? и унеслась чем?): Например, можно записать так:

*И она мысленно унеслась куда-то **далеко, в уже давно прошедшие годы.***

Другими словами, нужно обозначить, **куда  именно она унеслась.** Варианты оформления подобных выражений можно посмотреть [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

*На её лице мелькнула грустная улыбка, и она опять мысленно **унеслась куда-то**.*

***Мыслями он снова унёсся к сарматам** и заново прожил годы, проведённые там.*

*Да, очень похоже, – улыбнулась в ответ сестра, и **её мысли унеслись туда,** на загадочный кусочек земли, который появился так вовремя и не дал девушкам погибнуть.*

Answer (score 2):

Заглянем в толковый словарь:

[**унестись**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) — **2.** Перенестись куда-либо (о мыслях, мечтах и т. п.). *Мысли унеслись в прошлое. Воображение унеслось в мир фантазий.* // Мысленно перенестись куда-либо; погрузиться в мечты, фантазии и т. п. (о человеке). *Унестись мыслями, мечтами куда-либо. Кто-либо унёсся в мир приключений. Унестись в прошлое. Унестись в воспоминания*;

**воспоминание** — **1.** Мысленное воспроизведение чего-либо прошедшего, сохранившегося в памяти. *Воспоминания детства. Предаться воспоминаниям. Осталось одно воспоминание* (ничего материального, кроме приятного впечатления, удовольствия и т. п.).

- Так что, да, плеоназм имеется.
  Если используем "мысленно", то "воспоминаниями" — лишнее.

Вот что нашлось в Нацкорпусе:
*Машинально слѣдя за танцующими, она **мысленно унеслась** въ голубую гостиную, куда вотъ уже мѣсяцъ почти каждый вечеръ являлся Вильдъ* (Е. И. Апрелева. Без вины виноватые // «Вестник Европы», №№ 7–8, 1877);
*...подруга начисто забыла о своих житейских проблемах и **мыслями унеслась** в Тихий океан, в район двадцатой параллели* (Марина Полетика. Однажды была осень);
***Мыслью унеслась** чародейка в давно прошедшее, когда ее так радовала полученная ею на новых местах власть почти на полгода сковывать твердую землю, болота и реки* (А. А. Кондратьев. На берегах Ярыни. Демонологический роман).

- Словосочетание "мысленно унестись" вполне гармонично, встречается нередко.

*Парень мысленно унесся далеко-далеко.

Я мысленно унёсся вслед за этими импульсами.

Мысленно унеслась куда-то далеко отсюда...

Мысленно унеслась на далекий остров.

Анастасия мысленно унеслась в то счастливое время...*

Answer (score 1):

‟Унеслась воспоминаниями” – тут всё в порядке, это некий фигуральный приём – словно воспоминания взяли и унесли её. Сочетание ‟мысленно унеслась воспоминаниями” – это определённо плеоназм, потому что нельзя унестись воспоминаниями не мысленно. Вспоминание уже предполагает мыслительную деятельность.

Answer (score 0):

В предложении практически нереально уловить корректную структуру передаваемой мысли, хотя теоретически возможно.
**Воспоминаниями** может быть либо субъектом действия, либо частью субъекта действия, либо средством действия. Первый вариант звучит бредово (Пыль унеслась ветром), второй вариант не напрашивается, его надо подчеркивать порядком слов:

```
Своими воспоминаниями (своей частью) она мысленно унеслась куда-то далеко.
```